# Couchbase Ghost entry - Have it in view, not in data itself

Tags: view, couchbase

I have a 4 server setup.

In them I have a view like this:

```
function (doc, meta) {
    if(meta.type == "json") {
        if(doc.type && doc.type == "saveDocument") {
            emit(meta.id, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that right now I have as first reply from it record with key ""cache::1433576113.9028" but when I try to Remove it from the system all I am getting is "Key not present" error.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

What is interested I have changed the view, to show me the data itself and the data was OK...

Well, I have Failed Over each server one by one, and made a FULL REBALANCE after the failure.
After I have finished with the last 4th server, the ghost record disappeared.